# Solve linear system of equations

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a system of equations,

```
constant + C.x + D.y = P
```

where `C` and `D` are 25*4 matrices. `x` and `y` are 4*1 matrices and `P` is a 25*1 matrix. How do I solve this system of equations in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)?

Comment: This question needs a lot of work. Can you show us what you've tried? Have you tried googling a little bit? What operator did the first 2 or 3 google hits say you should look at? As it stands there is a great risk this will be closed as not a real question.

Comment: @Paindoo It seems that your linear equation is overdetermined. You have 25 equations and only 8 unknowns.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Matrices C, D and P are known and x and y are to be determined. x and y are not scalers but 4*1 matrices

Comment: @Eitan, yes, it is an overdetermined set of equations.

Comment: @Paindoo then you should take a look at the following related question: [Solving an overdetermined constraint system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118274/solving-an-overdetermined-constraint-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the equations as

```
 [C D] * [x ;y ] = P - constant
```

where `[C D]` is a horizontal concatenation of `C` and `D` ( 25 * 8 matrix ).
`[x;y]` is a *vertical* concatenation of `x` and `y` ( 8*1 vector )

You can solve this in Matlab using [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
 xy = [C D] \ ( P - constant ); 

 x = xy(1:4);
 y = xy(5:end);
```

Comment: Yes, but this is homework! Teach a man to fish......